# Ruby C Extension: rb_funcall causing segfault

Tags: c, ruby, api, segmentation-fault

My extension uses a Ruby library  to send and receive command and telemetry packets over an interface and gives them to a C file transfer library for processing.

After receiving a lot of packets, I'll get this segfault. Here's the backtrace from GDB.

```
            #0  search_method (defined_class_ptr=<synthetic pointer>, id=6177, klass=<optimized out>) at vm_method.c:567
            #1  rb_method_entry_get_without_cache (klass=19934160, id=6177, defined_class_ptr=0x12c5500) at vm_method.c:592
            #2  0x00007ffff7aced90 in rb_method_entry (klass=klass@entry=19934160, id=<optimized out>, 
                defined_class_ptr=defined_class_ptr@entry=0x12c5500) at vm_method.c:663
            #3  0x00007ffff7acee71 in vm_search_method (ci=ci@entry=0x12c54c0, recv=<optimized out>) at vm_insnhelper.c:842
            #4  0x00007ffff7ad4b3d in vm_exec_core (th=th@entry=0x6035d0, initial=initial@entry=0) at insns.def:1068
            #5  0x00007ffff7ad951b in vm_exec (th=th@entry=0x6035d0) at vm.c:1440
            #6  0x00007ffff7adac91 in vm_call0_body (th=th@entry=0x6035d0, ci=ci@entry=0x7fffffffbcb0, argv=0x7fffffffbd60)
                at vm_eval.c:180
            #7  0x00007ffff7adb6c6 in vm_call0 (defined_class=<optimized out>, me=<optimized out>, argv=<optimized out>, 
                argc=1, id=14481, recv=22956880, th=0x6035d0) at vm_eval.c:59
            #8  rb_call0 (recv=recv@entry=22956880, mid=14481, argc=argc@entry=1, argv=argv@entry=0x7fffffffbd60, 
                scope=scope@entry=CALL_FCALL, self=<optimized out>) at vm_eval.c:349
            #9  0x00007ffff7adbc64 in rb_call (scope=CALL_FCALL, argv=0x7fffffffbd60, argc=1, mid=<optimized out>, 
                recv=22956880) at vm_eval.c:616
            #10 rb_funcall (recv=recv@entry=22956880, mid=<optimized out>, n=n@entry=1) at vm_eval.c:818
            #11 0x00007ffff6092b10 in DL_RecvPdu () at CFGroundClient.c:414
            #12 0x00007ffff6092dbe in method_run (self=<optimized out>) at CFGroundClient.c:302
            #13 0x00007ffff7ace272 in vm_call_cfunc_with_frame (ci=0x0, reg_cfp=0x7ffff7fd1f70, th=0x6035d0)
                at vm_insnhelper.c:1380
            #14 vm_call_cfunc (th=th@entry=0x6035d0, reg_cfp=reg_cfp@entry=0x7ffff7fd1f70, ci=ci@entry=0xa29090)
                at vm_insnhelper.c:1473
            #15 0x00007ffff7ae0f6e in vm_call_method (th=0x6035d0, cfp=0x7ffff7fd1f70, ci=0xa29090) at vm_insnhelper.c:1689
            #16 0x00007ffff7ad4b4b in vm_exec_core (th=th@entry=0x6035d0, initial=initial@entry=0) at insns.def:1069
            #17 0x00007ffff7ad951b in vm_exec (th=th@entry=0x6035d0) at vm.c:1440
            #18 0x00007ffff7adaa73 in rb_iseq_eval_main (iseqval=iseqval@entry=10626960) at vm.c:1685
            #19 0x00007ffff798707d in ruby_exec_internal (n=0xa22790) at eval.c:254
            #20 0x00007ffff798948d in ruby_exec_node (n=n@entry=0xa22790) at eval.c:319
            #21 0x00007ffff798bc3e in ruby_run_node (n=0xa22790) at eval.c:311
            #22 0x000000000040087b in main (argc=3, argv=0x7fffffffde58) at main.c:36
```

Here is the relevant code:

```
                void DL_RecvPdu() {
                       .....
                    /* Segfault coming from here 
                       CUR_PACKET.read("PDU_DATA"); 
                       Reads telemetry item PDU_DATA from packet CUR_PACKET
                       and returns results. PDU data is an array of bytes 
                       represented as a Ruby string that can contain nulls */
                    VALUE pdu_data_block = rb_funcall(rb_CUR_PACKET, 
                        rb_READ, 1, 
                        rb_PDU_DATA
                    );
                        ....
                }
```

Does anyone know where this error could come from and how I can fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a number of possible causes for the issue and not (it seems) enough data.

One explanation could be that the Ruby objects (i.e `rb_CUR_PACKET`, `rb_READ` or `rb_PDU_DATA`) aren't valid by the time you called the function, since they might have been collected by the GC (Garbage Collector).

If the Objects aren't referenced by a Ruby object, their memory might be freed sooner than you expect.

An easy solution would be to register the Objects as a global objects (they will never be freed) or assign them as variables inside a user's object.

Another possible cause is that you aren't executing your code within the GIL (global instruction lock).

Ruby MRI code must always run within the GIL and within Ruby threads. If you left the GIL or spawned new threads that aren't Ruby threads, your code will crash if you're lucky.

I suspect the GC, but it's a toss.

Good Luck!

Comment: What other data would you need? 
Also:
rb_CUR_PACKET is received in a call shortly before the code snippet I included.

I made all of the variables used by that function call global and I still have the issue.

Looking into the GIL right now.